# change value of one dataframe by value from other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe df1

```
id    value
1       100
2       100
3       100
4       100
5       100
```

i have another dataframe df2

```
id    value
2       50
5       30
```

i want to replace these values for id's in df2 with the values in df1.
final modified df1:

```
id    value
1       100
2       50
3       100
4       100
5       30
```

i will be running this in a loop. i'e df2, will change time to time (df1, outside loop)

what would be the best way to change the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html), but first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) by `id` in both `DataFrame`s:

Notice: `id` column in `df2` has to be unique.

```
df = df2.set_index('id').combine_first(df1.set_index('id')).reset_index()
print (df)
   id  value
0   1  100.0
1   2   50.0
2   3  100.0
3   4  100.0
4   5   30.0
```

Answer (score 1):

A `loc` based solution -

```
i = df1.set_index('id')
j = df2.set_index('id')

i.loc[j.index, 'value'] =  j['value']
```

```
df2 = i.reset_index()
df2

   id  value
0   1    100
1   2     50
2   3    100
3   4    100
4   5     30
```